# Using nullable types in Linq expressions

Tags: c#, linq, nullable

```
var quantSubset =
    from userAns in userAnalysis.AllUserAnswers
    join ques in userAnalysis.AllSeenQuestions on userAns.QID equals ques.QID
    where (ques.QuestionType == "QT")
    select new {
        QuestionLevel = ques.LevelID,
        TimeTaken = userAns.TimeTaken,
        Points = userAns.Points,
        UsedWeapon = (userAns.UsedBy2 && userAns.UsedHint),
        WasCorrect = userAns.WasCorrect.HasValue ? userAns.WasCorrect.Value : null
    };
```

In my select expression I want to select a nullable type WasCorrect (last part of the expression) but apparently I cannot do it the way I am currently trying.

How can I get WasCorrect as nullable type

I tried ?WasCorrect but that also doesnt gives error in Visual Studio.

Comment: And what was the actual you error you encountered?

Comment: does ?WasCorrect = userAns.WasCorrect not work?

Comment: No I get the following error if I do ?WasCorrect Syntax error "," expected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast the `null` value to the nullable type explicitly:

```
WasCorrect = userAns.WasCorrect.HasValue ?
    userAns.WasCorrect.Value : (TheTypeName?)null
```

Otherwise C# won’t know which type the conditional expression should be.

Apart from that, the code is completely redundant. You can simply write:

```
WasCorrect = userAns.WasCorrect
```

Comment: @RPM: You do when the compiler needs to infer the type.  e.g., `var val = null; //null what?`

Comment: @Konrad Well, I have previously written code just the way you say but whenever it encounters a null value it throws an exception. See details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: @sassyboy: What details should I see on the page you linked? The code I wrote **never** throws an exception. You probably wrote `WasCorrect = userAns.WasCorrect.Value` by mistake instead.

Comment: Something tells me he tried to explicitly cast it to a bool when the value was null.  `var b = (bool)x.WasCorrect;` (or whatever type it is)

Comment: @konrad ok.. my bad.. a few days ago i had wrote an if condition, if (userAns.WasCorrect) and got an error when a value was null, so after that I have been checking everywhere (userAns.WasCorrect.HasValue). Let me try out what you have pointed out.

Comment: Yup it works.. so I guess it works fine with assignment but now on conditional.. makes sense.. thanks all..

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely must be able to write

```
select new { WasCorrect = userAns.WasCorrect }
```

if `userAns.WasCorrect` is `Nullable<bool>`.

This code executes without a problem:

```
class Test {
    public bool? NullableBool { get; set;}
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main ()
    {
        Test t1 = new Test { NullableBool = true };
        var a1 = new { NB = t1.NullableBool };

        Test t2 = new Test { NullableBool = null };
        var a2 = new { NB = t2.NullableBool };
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, sure. I only posted this as an answer for the proof code to fit.