# How to return a 'Guid' from a 'Nullable<Guid>'?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to return a **Guid** value below.  However the database(*and my dbml*) has that column as a `nullable Guid` and it is generating an exception on the `.Select` portion saying it can't convert from an `IQueryable<System.Guid?>` to a `System.Guid`.

I am guessing I need to make my return value "***concrete***" first???? True?
If so how do I do that with Guid's?

```
public static Guid GetCurrentWorkerByType(int enrollmentID, int staffTypeID)
{
    using (var context = CmoDataContext.Create())
    {
        IQueryable<tblWorkerHistory> tWorkHist = context.GetTable<tblWorkerHistory>();

        return (tWorkHist.Where(workHist => 
            (workHist.EnrollmentID == enrollmentID) &&
            (workHist.tblStaff.StaffTypeID == staffTypeID) &&
            (workHist.EndDate == null || workHist.EndDate > DateTime.Now))
            .Select(workHist => workHist.Worker));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821054/using-nullable-types-in-linq-expressions.

Comment: Does `public static Guid?` work?

Comment: What do you want to return if the database column row value is `null` then?

Comment: Austin Salonen - not it wouldn't

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
// Get the Guid? itself, for sake of example from IQueryable<Guid?>
// (could be `null` from DB value or because queryable was empty)
Guid? maybeGuid = queryable.FirstOrDefault();
// Need to have *a* GUID or default it to something
// because a Guid is a value-type and needs *a* value.
Guid theGuid = maybeGuid ?? Guid.Empty;
```

Also see `Nullable<T>.HasValue/Value` -- A longer, but equivalent, method would be:

```
Guid theGuid = maybeGuid.HasValue ? maybeGuid.Value : Guid.Empty;
```

Observe that `HasValue` may be suitable in general `if` statements to change logic and also note that `Value` will throw an exception if maybeGuid is "has no value" -- is `null` -- which is why the guard is required.

Happy coding.

---

Pedantic detail: The equivalent method is not "thread safe". That is, assuming `maybeGuid` was shared, it could be assigned `null` between `HasValue` and `Value`. There are a number of SO questions that cover the "thread safety" of `??` (the coalesce operator) -- the generated IL effectively uses a temporary variable so the value may be stale but an exception can't be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

What you've got is a query that hasn't executed for one, and for two, it will return a list of Guids as far as I can tell. If you want to return the first Guid or default (which I believe is a zero'd out guid) you can say .FirstorDefault() after your select.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
.Select(workHist => workHist.Worker).Single();
```

- `.Select()` returns a query that has not run.
- If you use `.Select().ToList()` then you you return a list.
- If you use `.Select().Single()` then you return one item and **it makes sure** only one item is there
- If you use `.Select().SingleOrDefault()` then you return one item and default. Query must not contain more than 1 item.
- If you use `.Select().First()` then you return the first item. Query must contain at least 1 item.
- If you use `.Select().FirstOrDefault()` then you return the first item or default. Query can contain 1 or more or no items.

Answer (score 2):

Try
    Change your return type from System.Guid to ?System.Guid // nullable of guid
    Then add .FirstOrDefault() after the select call

A struct cannot be null, but the System.Nullable class wraps the struct in a class.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you will get representing `null` with a `Guid` is to use `Guid.Empty`. So, for your query, you will probably want to first pick the value returned by `FirstOrDefault`, make a null check, and then return a reasnable value:

```
Guid? result = tWorkHist.Where(workHist => 
                   (workHist.EnrollmentID == enrollmentID) 
                   && (workHist.tblStaff.StaffTypeID == staffTypeID) 
                   && (workHist.EndDate == null || workHist.EndDate > DateTime.Now))
                   .Select(workHist => workHist.Worker)
                   .FirstOrDefault();

return result.HasValue ? result.Value : Guid.Empty;
```

Comment: +1 Why the downvote here? Other than the fact that it could use the null-coalescing `??` operator instead of the more verbose ternary syntax (and also avoid the temp variable as a result), I don't see what's wrong with this considering the other answers.

Comment: @Adam: I assume that it came from the first version of the text answering the question in the title (basically the first sentence). The downvote came while I formatted the code sample.

Comment: Guid.Empty is not null so it return 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 when the database had null

Comment: @James: I have not made any claim that `Guid.Empty` is null (it obviously can't be,`Guid` being a value type). But the question is *How to return a 'Guid' from a 'Nullable<Guid>'?* Given that scenario, I would say that `Guid.Empty` represents the one value that seem most logical to use as a substitution for a `null` value. Clearly, if you truly want to represent a `null` value, changing the return type to `Guid?` is the way to go, but there may be any number of reasons that makes such a change not being an option.

Comment: What was the ?Guid return type for as your example never returns null, either Guid.Empty with return type Guid or null with return type ?Guid

Comment: @James: Ah, now I see what you are getting at. I made the assumption that `workHist.Worker` is a `Guid?`, and that that was the root of the original problem. If that assumption is wrong (which it might very well be), your comments are correct; the query would never return a null, and the whole construct around `result` and the ternary operator stuff (which really should have been a null-coalescing operator) would be completely unnecessary.

Comment: I also made the assumption that workHist.Worker was of type ?Guid. I just meant that returning Guid.Empty instead of null when the return type was Nullable of Guid was wrong. Can you change to just return result; ?

Comment: @James: The OP has a method that is currently defined as returning a `Guid`, and the query produces a `Guid?`. There are two ways to solve it: one is to change the method signature to return a `Guid?` instead, and all is good. If that is not possible (which it may not be for any number of reasons), you will instead need to return some valid `Guid` value, that can logically subsitute `null`, such as `Guid.Empty`, which is what my answer suggests.

Comment: @Fredrik Mork:  You are correct, I did need to return a `Guid` Value as stated in my question.  Thanks for the help, sorry your detailed answer, somehow, recieved 2 downvotes.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Use FirstOrDefault with conjunticon with Guid.Empty

Try this:

```
public static Guid GetCurrentWorkerByType(int enrollmentID, int staffTypeID)
{
 using (var context = CmoDataContext.Create())
 {
  IQueryable<tblWorkerHistory> tWorkHist = context.GetTable<tblWorkerHistory>();
    var guid = (tWorkHist.Where(workHist => (workHist.EnrollmentID == enrollmentID) && 
                    (workHist.tblStaff.StaffTypeID == staffTypeID) &&(workHist.EndDate == null || workHist.EndDate > DateTime.Now))
        .Select(workHist => workHist.Worker)
     ///####NOTICE THE USE OF FirstOrDefault
        ).FirstOrDefault();
    return (guid.HasValue)?guid.Value:Guid.Empty
    }
}
```