# How to get nullable item from a LINQ2SQL query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ2SQL query for retrieving an ID (PK, not null). Here is that query:

```
int masterEntityID;
int payeeID;
int chargePayeeID;
try
{
    using (TestDataContext os = new TestDataContext())
    {
        string entityName = tbSearch.Text;

        var getMasterID = from r in os.Entities
                          where r.Name == entityName
                          select r.ID; 

        masterEntityID = getMasterID.First(); //this is working FINE!

        var getPayeeID = from pid in os.Entities
                         where pid.Name == entityName
                         select pid.Payee_ID;

        payeeID = getPayeeID.First(); //This is giving me an err: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)   



    };
```

Both the datatypes: ID and Payee_ID are of int. But ID is Pkey and Payee_ID is Not!

How to get the value from getPayeeID to payeeID? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return a 'Guid' from a 'Nullable<Guid>'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668673/how-to-return-a-guid-from-a-nullableguid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getPayeeID.First().GetValueOrDefault()
```

Comment: This is the best (safest) option as long as you are happy to have the value set to 0 when a null value is returned. Forgot about that method.

Comment: GetValueOrDefault should return null if Payee_ID is nullable property or i m missing something

Comment: @Muhammad it will return `default()` of the variable

Answer (score 2):

If your confident that Payee_Id won't ever be null then just cast the value:

```
payeeID = (int)getPayeeID.First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the value is `int?` you can get the `int` from it using the `Value` property:

```
payeeID = getPayeeID.First().Value;
```

`int?` is shorthand for [`Nullable<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use FirstOrDefault() or declare payeeID as a int? and then use it as you want (if it is null you should try to do anything...)

Answer (score -1):

it seems that Payee_ID property of your entity is nullable that is because it represents a nullable column in the database. so, you should not be receiving its value in int that is not nullable. you can get its value in nullable int like.

```
int? payeeID = payeeID = getPayeeID.FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var payeeID = payeeID = getPayeeID.FirstOrDefault();
```

later you can check if payeeID value was null or not using

```
if(payeeID.HasValue)
{
        int x = payeeID.Value; //Value property of nullable int is an integer value and accessing it would through exception if HasValue property is false
}
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault will return the default value of the type that is nullable in the case that it is null. Therefore it will return 0 if the first item of getPayeeId is null.